# How does one compute the components of the stress tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how the Stress tensor works and functions and all it can do, but I'm not entirely sure at how you actually get the components of its matrix. For example, if you have a sphere and you have a vector$$v=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$  at the surface of that sphere going outwards away from that sphere representing a force being acted on that sphere, the stress that is being acted on on that sphere is that vector *v* times the stress tensor.
$$
T_{mn}=\begin{bmatrix}
T_{xx}\ T_{xy}\ T_{xz}\\
T_{yx}\ T_{yy}\ T_{yz}\\
T_{zx}\ T_{zy}\ T_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So I was wondering how exactly one gets the components of that matrix **$T_{mn}$**.

Comment: I posted this question on the engineering stack exchange already and I didn't get an answer, so I thought that I would get an answer here quicker.

Comment: By a circle, do you mean a sphere?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant sphere.

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say "how does one compute the components"? Are you asking how one would perform measurements to determine the components? Otherwise, what exactly the information we have from which we're supposed to deduce the components of $T$?

Comment: Sorry that I'm unclear. I'm trying to say that I want to know what numbers go into that matrix *T*.

Comment: And how to compute those numbers.

Comment: It's clear what numbers you want, what is unclear is what information is available. As an analogy: suppose someone said "I want to figure out how long a ball will take to hit the ground if I drop it off a roof". If we have no information about the setup, then we can't say anything. Typically, the **information used** to determine the time it takes is the height of the building. For your problem, what **information** can we **use**?

Comment: I'm not asking a particular question that I was asked in a physics class or something, but more of a generalization. So, I'm asking what information is needed to compute the stress tensor and what to do with that information once I have it.

Comment: In principle, a stress tensor could be **any** symmetric (usually positive definite) $3 \times 3$ matrix. Unless we know something about the object that the stress tensor describes, we have no way of figuring out which matrix we will get.

Comment: As another analogy, it's as if you asked "how do I find the digits of a number?" Unless you say more about which number you're talking about or what information you have about that number (for example, "the number we want to find is the solution to a quadratic equation"), then there's nothing useful to be said.

Comment: If you're asking how to *interpret* the numbers that form the matrix, then you might find it useful to note that $T_{xx}$ denotes the normal stress against the $yz$-plane at a point, and $T_{xy}$ denotes the $y$-component of the shear stress along the $yz$-plane at that point. Similarly, all diagonal elements are normal stresses, and the off diagonal elements are shear stresses.

Comment: Kay, then let's say that I want to find the stress tensor of a sphere

Comment: **Strain determines stress:** Let's assume that the body is [hyperelastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelastic_material) with a known stress-energy function $W$. If you know the deformation the body has undergone, then you have a deformation gradient (field) $\mathbf{F}$ defined on the reference configuration. The first Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor is the derivative $\mathbf{P} = \partial W/\partial\mathbf{F}$, and the [Cauchy stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelastic_material#Cauchy_stress) is $\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{F}^{T}/\det(\mathbf{F})$.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have to ask this but, how do those equations account for all of the stress tensor matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Some common ways of obtaining simple models of the stress tensor (given a physical description of an object) are [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)#General_stress). More generally, the problem of finding the stress tensor at all points within an object lies in the domain of [stress analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_analysis).

A relatively simple means of doing so for an arbitrary object (with the assumption that the strain on the object is not enough to "significantly" dent/displace it) is [infinitesimal strain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory).  Here, one uses the [deformation gradient tensor](https://www.continuummechanics.org/deformationgradient.html) (which encodes the strain on the object) to find the Cauchy stress tensor.  In this context, the Cauchy stress tensor at a point is also referred to as the "infinitesimal strain tensor".

To extend this analysis to a more general setting (with "significant" strains and dents), one would use [finite strain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_strain_theory), which is what was alluded to in the comments.